# Empty statemachine base?

Tags: java-me, lwuit

hello I recently started using Resource editor and I have a question:I 'm trying to create a simple project just for test purposes in Resource Editor:nothing special just a Label with a hello world, but when I push "create Netbeans project" while all the projects(JavaSE,MIDP ,RIM) are created none of them are running. In normal JaVA I just get a black screen and in MIDP emulator I get a message saying "This application runs in the background".

My StateMachineBase code is this

```
public class StateMachineBase {
    public StateMachineBase(String s) {}
}
```

And My StateMachine code is this:

```
public StateMachine(String resFile) {
    super(resFile);
    // do not modify, write code in initVars and initialize class members there,
    // the constructor might be invoked too late due to race conditions that might occur
}

/**
 * this method should be used to initialize variables instead of
 * the constructor/class scope to avoid race conditions
 */
protected void initVars() {
}
```

So I'm guessing my prgramm obviously won't do anything since there is no code. What am I doing wrong? From my understanding StateMachineBase should have all the boiler code.I'm using Netbeans 6.9.1 ,Lwuit latest version  and JavaME SDK 3.0 and Nokia S60 SDK.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well I shall answer my own post. Randomly I found out that if you save the res file and reopen it then it works fine. This was confirmed by Shai Almog in his blog saying that this is a bug that will be fixed in the next release.

[Shai's answer to my post](http://www.blogger.com/comment.g?blogID=3844993555541859586&postID=8316975609122902825)